# Leaflet extra markers displaying icon but not marker

Tags: leaflet, markers, icon

My code for formatting a JS Leaflet Extra Marker is like below where I've clearly given a marker color.

```js
let parkMarkerIcon = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
  shape: 'circle',
  markerColor: 'green',
  prefix: 'fa-solid',
  icon: 'fa-tree"',
  iconColor: '#fff',
  iconRotate: 0,
  extraClasses: '',
  number: '',
  svg: false
});
```

However, I don't seem to be getting the marker, just the icon?
See below
[image]

Have I missed something?
I've tried looking at other working examples but they don't seem to include anything more than what I have above.

Comment: Which versions of Leaflet,  `L.ExtraMarkers` and Fonts Awesome are you using? I had no problems displaying icon with Leaflet 1.8.0 and Fonts Awesome 4.4.0, just had to put `prefix: 'fa'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It is either your css file is not properly linked, or your images are in the wrong folder. For me, I moved my images to a directory above my css file and it worked. We know your js is working, otherwise the icon wouldn't appear at all.